# Any difference between the .I and **-1 for matrix inversion in mpmath?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I know that you can invert a matrix as follows:

A.I, A**-1 in python, and I was wondering if there is any difference. The reason I ask is that I'm thinking of using **mpmath** for high precision and it only supports the **-1 implementation.

Thank you

EDIT:

To add some clarification:

I am wondering if `.I` is shorthand for `**-1` or if it calls `np.linalg.inv` or some other function.

Comment: You mean A.I for normal precision and A**-1 for high precision?

Comment: I don't understand your question. A.I is not available for mpmath matrices, but **-1 is. I was wondering if .I is shorthand for **-1 or if it calls np.linalg.inv or some other function

Comment: OK, please update the post as you commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bet you can find your answers in the numpy matrix code:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py

```
def matrix_power....
    '''
    If ``n < 0``, the inverse is computed and then raised to the ``abs(n)``
    ...
    matrix Provides an equivalent function as the exponentiation operator (``**``, not ``^``).
    '''
    from numpy.linalg import inv
    ...
    elif n<0:
        M = inv(M)
        n *= -1
```

for the `matrix` class

```
def __pow__(self, other):
    return matrix_power(self, other)
```

for `M.I` look at `M.getI` (`IPython` is a handy way of looking at the code without pulling up the source files, e.g. `M.getI??`)

Comment: thanks! This is exactly what I was asking. How do I use ipython to find what I want? do you mean by `help(M.getI)` ?

Comment: ok found it! I'll add it to your answer!